# Is there a C++ dependency index somewhere?

Tags: c++, dependencies, makefile

When trying new software and compiling with the classic `./configure`, `make`, `make install` process, I frequently see something like:

```
error: ____.h: No such file or directory
```

Sometimes, I get really lucky and `apt-get install ____` installs the missing piece and all is well.  However, that doesn't always happen and I end up googling to find the package that contains what I need.  And sometimes the package is the wrong version or flavor and is already used by another package that I downloaded.

How do people know which packages contain which .h files or whatever resource the compiler needs?  Is there a dependency resolver website or something that people use to decode failed builds to missing packages?  Is there a more modern method of automatically downloading and installing transitive dependencies for a build (somewhat like Java's Maven)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use "auto-apt ./configure" (on Ubuntu, and probably also on Debian?) and it will attempt to download dependencies automatically.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a package in Debian, you can use `apt-get build-dep` to get all deps.

Otherwise, read the README that comes with the program -- hopefully, it lists all the deps for that program.

Answer (score 0):

The required packages will hopefully be listed in the documentation for building the package. If it says you require `foo`, you'll probably want to look for `foo` and `foo-devel`, and perhaps `libfoo-devel`. If that doesn't help, in Fedora I'd do something like

```
yum install install /usr/include/_____.h
```

(yum will look for the package containing said file). If none of the above works, look for the file name in Google, that should tell you the package where it comes from. But then the going will get rough...